# How to add Order Ref in pos receipt odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to add the order ref in POS's receipt.How Can I add ?

```html
<div class="pos-receipt-order-data">
                <div><t t-esc='receipt.name' /></div>
                <div><t t-esc='receipt.date.localestring' /></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I need to do the same.